# Google spreadsheet sorting messes up cell comments

Tags: google-sheets

I'm running into this weird problem with Google spreadsheets: if the cells have comments on them and I sort the spreadsheet, the rows sort but the comments stay in the same position, and don't move with the cells they're attached to.  In other words, the cells look like this:

```
A
C  <-- comment on this cell
B
```

and then I sort by this column:

```
A
B  <-- comment remains on this cell (stays in position)
C  <-- comment should have remained attached to this cell
```

This means that sorting is completely broken and I can't use it at all, because I clearly need the cell comments to stay with the cell they're attached to.  Is this a bad bug in Google Spreadsheets, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I can't reproduce the phenomenon you're describing. See file I've added and see for yourself. I've tried column sorting as well as the menu option: http://goo.gl/NWEJ1.

Comment: I have view access only, so I can't test it out.  Can you share with Everyone.  I should be more specific and add that I'm selecting a range of cells and choosing "Sort Range", not trying to sort by the whole column (because of the way the data are structured).

Comment: Frank, it's yours !!

Comment: Did you find the problem, causing the mayhem?

Comment: Thanks for following up, but not really.  I tried copying the data to a new sheet, but the comments didn't copy.  And then, somewhere in the process, it deleted all the comments entirely.  So I'm not too happy with Google Spreadsheets right now.  The data in those comments wasn't mission critical, but it's still pretty annoying.

Comment: I confirm this problem with comments being not moving in sync with the cells when resorting. Sorting on a commented column forth and back will show this problem. In addition, sorting also messes up cell references for me, which makes Google Spreadsheet useless for me at the moment.

Comment: @AndersE: can you share this doc with us, it see this phenomenon myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but, just to close the loop, during my various attempts to troubleshoot this problem, the spreadsheet just deleted all the comments, so that fixed my problem in one sense, I guess.  I don't really have any idea what was causing the initial problem, or the data deletion.  It's a fairly big spreadsheet, with multiple collaborators, so maybe it got corrupted.  Boo, Google.

Comment: Your answer will be moderated.....Let us know if we can help once more.

Comment: Hi Frank, Was it a glitch in the matrix, or have you seen this problem again?

Comment: I haven't seen it again, but I haven't really been using comments, because I don't want to lose my work again.

Comment: Just happened / happens to me still. Ridiculous. How can I notify Google of this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Were you using the filter button to filter/sort or was it turned on at the time?

What can happen is that if you have that filter turned on, but it is not properly wrapped around the entire data set it will only sort the data it IS wrapped around -

what I do instead of using the filter to sort, is click on the tiny arrow that shows up next to the column Letter Header itself, and choose sort on that menu instead  and that will ALWAYS sort your entire sheet.

[image]