# Google Spreadsheets Messes Up Comments When Sorted

Tags: google-sheets

I added comments to a bunch of cells. When I then sorted the cells, the comments did not follow their original cell and now was connected to the new cell.  This is a massive problem and now my comments are all messed up.

This is the same problem that was brought up here, but was not answered.  [Google spreadsheet sorting messes up cell comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36148/google-spreadsheet-sorting-messes-up-cell-comments)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like, the position of *comments* are absolute, that is, comments always stay at the row number/column number that you first assigned them to (however, if you cut and paste a data cell, the comment will follow along; if you copy and paste it, the comment will stay at its original position).

However, *notes* are  attached to the actual data point, meaning that if the data point moves during a sorting operation, the note will move as well (in addition, a note will move if you cut and paste a data cell, and it will get duplicated if you copy and paste it).

That is, right now it seems like your best bet is to use notes instead of comments. If this is a non-starter, then it seems like you're out of luck.